# How to create a same index if string of list in one row present in another rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a index column in pandas dataframe for every row if string in list of string is available in another row then I should apply same index for that new row

if string of row[0] is in row[1]
then index of row[1] should have row[0]

I try to write a code but it is giving error

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
data = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily'],
       'Hobbies': [['reading', 'hiking', 'painting'], ['swimming', 'biking'], 
        ['cooking', 'dancing'], ['reading', 'swimming'], ['hiking', 'painting']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# loop over each row of the dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # define a boolean mask for all rows except the current one
    mask = df.index != index
    # check if any string in the current row is present in the other rows
    if df.loc[mask, 'Hobbies'].apply(lambda x: any(item for item in row['Hobbies'] if item in x)).any():
        # set the index of the current row to the index of the other row
        df.at[index, 'Index'] = df.loc[mask, 'Index'].iloc[0]
    else:
        # assign a new index if no match is found
        df.at[index, 'Index'] = index

print(df)
```

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input (note the different index):

```
      Name                      Hobbies
A    Alice  [reading, hiking, painting]
B      Bob           [swimming, biking]
C  Charlie           [cooking, dancing]
D    David          [reading, swimming]
E    Emily           [hiking, painting]
```

You can consider your data as a graph with [`netwrokx`](https://networkx.org) and find the [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html):

```
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist(c for l in df['Hobbies'] for c in combinations(l, 2))

groups = {n: i for i, c in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)) for n in c}

df.index = (df.index.to_series()
              .groupby(df['Hobbies'].str[0].map(groups))
              .transform('first')
           )
```

Output:

```
      Name                      Hobbies
A    Alice  [reading, hiking, painting]
A      Bob           [swimming, biking]
C  Charlie           [cooking, dancing]
A    David          [reading, swimming]
A    Emily           [hiking, painting]
```

If you don't care about the original index replace the last line with:

```
df.index = df['Hobbies'].str[0].map(groups).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
      Name                      Hobbies
0    Alice  [reading, hiking, painting]
0      Bob           [swimming, biking]
1  Charlie           [cooking, dancing]
0    David          [reading, swimming]
0    Emily           [hiking, painting]
```

Connected components:

[image]